# Laravel with Vue - Strict MIME Type Error When Loading JavaScript Module Script

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

This error was showing in my Laravel with Vue 3, Vite project.
While running `npm run dev` it works as expected. But while running `npm run build`, the page is all broken, with a console error saying: "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of 'text/html'. Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

And given below is my vite.config.js file:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'


export default defineConfig({
    base: '/',
    publicDir: 'public/',
    build: {
        outDir: 'dist', // Or any other preferred directory
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/router', import.meta.url)),
            '@2_AdminPanel': '/public/2_AdminPanel',
            '@assets': __dirname + '/resources/js/assets',
            '@root': __dirname + '/resources/js/assets',
            '@front': __dirname + '/resources/assets/1_WebFrontend',
            '@admin': __dirname + '/resources/assets/2_AdminPanel',
            '@common': __dirname + '/resources/assets/0_Common',
            '__': __dirname + '/resources/js',
        },
    }
});
```

I tried adding `base: '/'` to my vite file like given in some other pages, but it didn't help.

Comment: Your web server should be serving `.js` files with the `application/javascript` MIME type. This is going to be a default configuration on most servers, so my best guess is it's actually serving a 404 error for some reason. You can confirm by checking your browser's network inspector and seeing what gets returned.